# How to include non-linear inverse related variables in a linear regression?

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, linear-model, nonlinear-regression

I am running a linear regression with multiple independent variables, and I would like to include a lagged predictor variable. My predictor variable is called `Duration` and I have plotted it against the lagged variable `lag1_duration`.

[image]

My first question is, does the relationship shown in the picture follow an inverse function? If so, how can I test the goodness of fit of this function?

In my opinion I see 3 main linear categories: the vertical line, the horizontal line, and the 45-degree line. Moreover, the majority of observations are simply clustered in the lower left corner.

Second, if the variables did follow an inverse relation, how would I include the lagged variable in my linear regression in R?

**UPDATE**

I should have mentioned i'm dealing with panel-type data, where I have millions of timestamped transactions executed by thousands of traders. 
I'm conducting a mixed effects Cox Proportional Hazards Model, which takes several weeks to run given the large data set I have. So I was hoping of getting some insight into the relationship of the autoregressive terms before I run the model.

Comment: It looks like some of the time the variable (which is right skew) is nearly independent from one time period to the next and at other times is highly dependent from one period to the next. To let us see what is going on, could you do a time series plot of the data (and if the data are always strictly >0, also the log data)?

Comment: In addition to @Glen_b's comment, can you also show a plot of the residuals of the "linear regression with multiple independent variables" vs the lagged duration? Preferably an [acf](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/acf.html) plot. You should also consider using models that have implemented autocorrelation structures.

Comment: Note that with multiple predictors it's not necessarily possible to infer the conditional relationship between the response and a predictor from their marginal relationship

Comment: The question certainly sounds like you are doing some sort of time series analysis.  How are you dealing with the dependencies?